# Radio buttons to choose through which $_POST get the content of a textarea

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I'd like to get a text through after a choice done between "**English**" and "**French**" (radio buttons) but I'm not sure how to associate both textareas and radio buttons.

```
<form action="_received-info.php" id="form_id" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="form-translation">

<p>Translation :</p> 

<label for="Translation"> English </label>
<input type="radio" name="Translation_EN" id="Translation_EN" value="Translation" checked>

<label for="Translation"> French </label>
<input type="radio" name="Translation_FR" id="Translation_FR" value="Translation">

<textarea name="Translation">
<!-- Text translated into English or French -->
</textarea>

</form>
```

Then I'd like to get that text on my **_received-info.php** page by doing a

```
$_POST['Translation_EN']; 
$_POST['Translation_FR'];
```

(one of them containing the text, the other empty).

Could anyone help me? Thank you in advance ^^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case

```
$_POST['Translation_EN'];
```

and

```
$_POST['Translation_FR'];
```

both contain 'Translation' when you echo them on the next page.

As those are radios, I suppose you only want to have one selectable? If so, give both the same name.

Like:

```
<label for="Translation"> English </label>
<input type="radio" name="Translation" id="Translation_EN" value="EN" checked>

<label for="Translation"> French </label>
<input type="radio" name="Translation" id="Translation_FR" value="FR">

<textarea name="Text_to_translate">
<!-- Text translated into English or French -->
</textarea>
```

On the next page, you can do:

```
switch ($_POST['Translation']) {

case 'FR':

//do something with $_POST['Text_to_translate'];

break;

case 'EN':

//do something with $_POST['Text_to_translate'];

break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Michael ! I didn't know I could proceed this way